# Compute $\lim_n \|u_n-\bar f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, periodic-functions

Let $p \in [1, \infty]$. Let $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (\mathbb R)$ be $T$-periodic, i.e., $f(x+T) = f(x)$ a.e. $x \in \mathbb R$. Let
$$
\bar f := \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f (t) \, dt.
$$

We define a sequence $(u_n) \subset L^p(0, 1)$ by $u_n (x) := f(nx)$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$. I'm trying to compute $\lim_n \|u_n-\bar f\|_p$. Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

Let $\varphi(n) := \lfloor n/T \rfloor$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\|u_n-\bar f\|_p^p &= \int_0^1 |f(nx)-\bar f|^p \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n |f-\bar f|^p \\
&= \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \int_0^{T} |f-\bar f|^p + \frac{1}{n} \int_{\varphi(n)T}^n |f-\bar f|^p.
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, $\frac{1}{n} \displaystyle\int_{\varphi(n)T}^n |f-\bar f|^p \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}0$. On the other hand,
$$
 \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \big \lfloor \frac{n}{T} \big \rfloor \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{T}.
$$

It follows that
$$
\lim_n \|u_n-\bar f\|_p = \bigg ( \frac{1}{T} \int_0^{T} |f-\bar f|^p \bigg)^{1/p}.
$$

Comment: It seems okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te calculation is actually much simpler that what you have.
Notice that if $\phi$ is $T$ periodic and say, locally integrable, then for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\int^{T+a}_a\phi=\int^T_0\phi$$

From that observation, along with  the change of variable $u=nx+b$, one gets
\begin{align} \int^T_0\phi(nx+b)\,dx&=\frac{1}{n}\int^{nT+b}_b\phi(u)\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\int^{(k+1)T+b}_{kT+b}\phi(u)\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\int^{(k+1)T}_{kT}\phi(u)\,du\\
&=\int^T_0\phi(u)\,dx\end{align}
In your case, take $\phi(x)=|f(x)-\overline{f}|$, where $f$ is a $1$-periodic function ($T=1$).

Comment: I could not see how your $\phi$ and your calculation are related to my question...

Comment: Let $\phi(x)=|f(x)-\overline{f}|$.  If  $f$ is $T$ periodic (in your case $T=1$), then so is $\phi$ . Notice $\phi(nx)=|f(nx)-\overline{f}|$

Comment: But in my case, I integrate on $[0, 1]$, whereas you integrate on $[0, T]$.

Comment: @Analyst: Take $T=1$, see my edit

Comment: That's why my calculation is longer than yours, i.e., $\varphi(n) := \lfloor n/T \rfloor$ may be not an integer, so I must take care of the "decimal" part.

Comment: You don't need $\varphi(n)=\lfloor n/T \rfloor$ at all! It is a direct computation.

Comment: What do you mean by "a direct computation"?

Comment: @Analyst: either  the $T$ in your OP should be $1$, to the interval of interest should be $(0,T)$. It seems that you are using this posting to fill in the details of your previous posting. There they use $L_p(0,1)$ and the periodic functions are all $1$-periodic. The results in your posting hold $1$ is replaced by $T$, i.e., if one considers  $L_p(0,T)$ and  $T$-periodic functions.

Comment: Could you give me the link to my previous question you are mentioning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145203/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-analyst).